# Strange loop behavior with JSON and AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

We have these files:
**Action.php**

```
<?php

$array = array(
    0 => array(
        'id' => "2",
        'name' => "Start",
        'password' => "start"
    ),
    1 => array(
        'id' => "3",
        'name' => "Med",
        'password' => 'med'
    ),
    2 => array(
        'id' => "4",
        'name' => "Last",
        'password' => 'last'
    )
);

echo json_encode($array);

?>
```

**Index.php**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="res-list">
            <div class="response" id="1">
                Name: <span class="name">Sample</span><br>
                Password: <span class="password">Test</span><br>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

and our **main.js**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'action.php',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(msg){
            $.each(msg, function(index, value){
                $('.response').clone().attr('id', value.id).appendTo('#res-list');
                $('#'+ value.id +' .name').html(value.name);
                $('#'+ value.id +' .password').html(value.password); 
            });
        },

        error: function(){
            $('.response').html("An error occurred");
        }
    });

});
```

Basically i'd like to output every element of `$array` in a different `<div class="response"></div>`

And it seems to be partially working. But instead of outputting:

```
Name: Sample
Password: Test
Name: Start
Password: start
Name: Med
Password: med
Name: Last
Password: last
```

it outputs

```
Name: Sample
Password: Test
Name: Start
Password: start
Name: Med
Password: med
Name: Start
Password: start
Name: Last
Password: last
Name: Start
Password: start
Name: Med
Password: med
Name: Start
Password: start
```

Comment: In order to avoid future troubles, be aware that it is not valid HTML4 to use numeric IDs. With `'id' => "2",` you're making the ID you assign to the cloned `.repsonse` numeric.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems to me that when you do this:

```
    $('.response').clone().attr('id', value.id).appendTo('#res-list');
```

You clone **all** the `<div>` elements with class "response". Maybe you should give the first one a separate class (or an "id" value) so that you can target it specifically, and make sure that the other ones don't have the class. You could of course just remove the class "response" from the cloned ones too:

```
    $('.response').clone().attr('id', value.id).removeClass('response').appendTo('#res-list');
```

Comment: Shouldn't `$('.response')` call just the first of matched elements?

Comment: @Charlie no, it definitely means **all** elements on the page with class "response".  That's what makes jQuery so useful :-)

Comment: @Charlie Nope; it matches all elements with that class. Try cloning `$('.response:first')`, or something along those lines.

Comment: Or cache the `.response` selection *before* the loop, then clone it inside (if the `response` class needs to be retained).

Answer (score 0):

When you clone "Response", you're cloning everything including the class, so the selector '.response' matches 2 elements after you append the first time.  So the 2nd time through the array, you're appending 2 new items, and on the 3rd time, you're appending 4.

To correct this, call .removeClass('response') on your cloned element.